# Named queries in webservices

Tags: web-services, hibernate, named-query

I want to retrieve all records with shelfId=1 and between two dates. I wrote a query like this in my webservice Its not working. can anyone please correct this one.

@NamedQuery(name = "BinEnvironment.BinEnvironmentByStartDateEndDate", query = "SELECT b FROM BinEnvironment b where shelfId ='?1' and dateTime between '1?' and '?2'")

Reply as soon as possible

Regards
Hema

Comment: this doesnt seem right: ` between '1?' and '?2` parameter declaration. And you are trying to use the same param for shelfId and dateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your parameter declaration: you are trying to use the same param for `shelfId` and `dateTime`.

The declaration of parameters for the `between` case shoudl probably be `between '?2' and '?3`.

Please note the [correct syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24396/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_pos_params) (use `?1` instead of `1?`):

> Input parameters are designated by the question mark (?) prefix followed by an integer. For example: ?1.